# Segmentation Fault on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I was developing a OpenGL program with Qt Creator and then a very strange fact happened.

My program was working, but now it isn't. I didn't perform any changes on it. Just to be sure, now I use an older version. It doesn't work anymore either. So, I decided do debug my application and realized that was occurring a Segfault. I wrote a `qDebug() <<(...)` in the first line of the main function, but nothing appears on the screen.

I had a similar segfault failure (when nothing is executed) once due to a huge static allocation. I've looked for similar issues in my code and was unable to find it.

Anyone has any idea what is going on?

I am using QtCreator with Qt 4.7 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: For one...constructors for static objects run before main even starts.  Have you loaded your program into a proper debugger and gotten a stack trace?  "printf debugging" is a pretty stone-age way of finding problems.  Even website developers use better these days.  :-P

Comment: My stack trace is empty... By the way, I ve just used "printf" as a desperate measure, since gdb was useless... =D

Comment: Well gdb is useless if you don't compile with debug flags.

Comment: So you must have changed something the program depends on, like moving a file that it opens, for instance. Before you do anything else, you should get a version control system like git or mercury and learn the basics. Also keep backups - Dropbox and similar services don't cost anything.

Comment: As I said, I kept a backup and it doesn't work anymore. It has all the files to work with a Qt environment (in theory). So, it is not a file issue.

Comment: Did you install anything new that might be using its own version of Qt? Are you sure it loads the exact libraries you expect it to? Similar issues have happened to me before where my program was using another piece of software's own bundled Qt version.

Comment: I seem to recall having some issues when I upgraded Ubuntu to 12.04. I think I needed to add some includes or library paths that were unnecessary before. It was something weird. But that happened right after the upgrade so it's probably not your problem.

Comment: Wow!! @Bart was right!! I've reinstalled Qt and now everything works! Thank you so much for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it reinstalling Qt. I believe I've messed its libraries when I was updating some programs. Hope it helps another people with similar issues! Thanks for the comments!